# How to create Many-One Mapping in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to create Many-One Mapping between two tabels, Expense(ID, NAME, CATEGORY) and
Category(ID, NAME). 
In my class i have created a field 'Category category' and its setters and getters.
I did them after seeing some stuff from internet. What are all the changes i have to do in my Category.java class. For now, its looks like,

```
public class Category{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int catId;
private String catName;

public Category() {
}

public int getCatId() {
    return this.catId;
}

public void setCatId(int catId) {
    this.catId = catId;
}

public String getCatName() {
    return this.catName;
}

public void setCatName(String catName) {
    this.catName = catName;
}

}
```

I dont want to do mappings with xml config. I think, annotations is good for a beginner like me.

And my Old! SQL query looks like,

`SELECT EXPENSES.EXPNS_ID, EXPENSES.CAT_ID, EXPENSES.NAME, CATEGORY.CAT_NAME FROM EXPENSES INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON EXPENSES.CAT_ID = CATEGORY.CAT_ID WHERE USER_NAME="+currentUserName`

How to use inner join in Hibernate?

Any Suggestions!!

Thanks!

---

**Update**

Thanks for all answerers,
I tried what you told and it returns a empty list.

To, test i set the 'userName=Tamil' which is in the table. 
The query generated by Hibernate is looks like below,

`select expens0_.expnsId as expnsId1_, expens0_.catId as catId1_, expens0_.category_catId as category7_1_, expens0_.userName as userName1_ from Expens expens0_ inner join Category category1_ on expens0_.category_catId=category1_.catId where expens0_.userName=?`

As a beginner, i have some doubts in JPQL, I want `catName` from `Category[catId, catName]` table. And the `catId` is also available in `Expens[expnsId, catId, userName]`.

By adding the below lines in Expens.java class, how it will give me `catName` along with the other variables in the `Expens` table.

```
@ManyToOne
private Category category

// getters, setters
```

I cant able to understand it. Without understanding this i cant move further, i have to give more mappings in my project. If clear with this mapping, i can move to the rest with confidence.

The query i used is pascal's version: `Query query = hSession.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Expens e JOIN e.category c WHERE e.userName = :userName").setParameter("userName", userName);`

For me, the query generated by hibernate is looks like same as my Old SQl query. I cant able to find problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, a big part of the documentation that would be useful in your case is located in the Hibernate Annotations Reference Guides (links provided below). Reading it would be **very** worth it.

That being said, regarding your specific question, the simplest possible mapping would be:

```
@Entity
public class Expense {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category

    // getters, setters
    ...
}
```

That's all.

If you want to make it bi-directional, you'll have to add a `OneToMany` on the other side (and don't forget the `mappedBy` element since the association is bidirectional):

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    private Set<Expense> expenses = new HashSet<Expense>();
    ....
}
```

And a possible JPQL query would be:

```
SELECT e FROM Expense e JOIN e.category c WHERE e.username = :username
```

---

**Update:** Hibernate and JDBC are different. With Hibernate, you need to think objects and the above HQL query (which was more an example) will actually return a `List<Expense>`. To get a category name, iterate over the results and navigate through the association. For example:

```
List<Expense> expenses = ... // some code to retrieve a list by username

for (Expense expense : expenses) {
    System.out.println(expense.getCategory().getName());
}
```

#### References

- [2.2. Mapping with JPA (Java Persistence Annotations)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping)
- [2.2.5.2. Many-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1508)

Comment: Thanks! I tried the things you have told. I updated the result and some doubts in my question. i hope you will answer for them.

Comment: I also want to tell you that the links you provided is very helpful for me. I just red the Many-To-One part alone. After seeing the link, it reminded me about the time period i wasted in searching of Many-To-One in the internet.

Comment: @pascal: ya it helped, But, you never replied for my updates in my question. I have a huge list in there. I am still strucking in them, you know.

Comment: @MaRaVan Maybe I also have a huge list in there. Maybe I don't have *your* database and can't debug it for you. Maybe I didn't understand that the "problem" wasn't solved. For me, the original problem *is* solved.

Comment: @Pascal: Hey, don't take it bad. Actually what i am trying is, i have got a object, its one of property is in another table. If you see the Query generated by hibernate means, you can fully understand my problem. After `on` expens0_.category_catId=category1_.catId, see its checking with the same values from the same table. I did the things you suggested. Create Category category; and its setters getters. Annotated with @ManyToOne. Then, still why its checking with same values of same entity. I am a beginner, i cant figure it out. Give me a hand!!!

Comment: @MaRaVan I did, I was updating my answer.

Comment: @Pascal: Well, i am fully responsible for my questions. But if the questions were funny or insane or meaningless, i dont care. Because, i am not doing this for purpose. I don't know, how actually express the thing. I am a beginner. I will laugh on me, after i got enough knowledge and reading the same questions in future. On the time me too will feel like funny or insane or meaningless.

Comment: @MaRaVan I'm not following you, I don't know what you're talking about. But just in case a clarification is required, my previous comment was an answer to *"Give me a hand!"*.

Comment: @Pascal: Again, you took it badly... I am sorry for that. Actually, i what i am trying to say is, "i thought you were not answering for my update, because of my question is meaningless". Professionals often do like that. I do not blame them, because that is their nature. Me too will also do like that, in future(i ll became professional in what i do). I am just explaining myself. "But if the questions were funny or insane or meaningless, i dont care" means, i am dont actually know the question is meaningless, because i am noob now. Again sorry, if those words irritates you. Sorry man!!! Cool.

Comment: @MaRaVan I didn't take anything badly, don't worry. And I usually let people know if I understood their question or any follow-up, or not, especially if I started answering. Just be patient :)

Comment: @MaRaVan By the way, does the last update answer pending questions?

Comment: @Pascal: Many, Many thanks for asking. Ya, i have one. After long time of working on this only, i started to think like object. Now only, i clearly understand what one-to-many & Many-to-One in object view. My latest error is 

` Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Category, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(expenses)]]'`

Now i am searching for this in the internet. And also thinking of posting another question for this!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `Expense` class have:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")
private Category category
```

As pointed in the comments, *if* you need to access all expenses in a given category, i.e. have the one-to-many relationship, you can have:

```
@OneToMany
private List<Expense> expenses;
```

I, for example, prefer to use as little `@OneToMany` mappings as possible - you'd have to manager eager/lazy loading, at some point limiting the number of results, etc. For them I tend to use HQL queries that fetch the subset of objects (expenses in your case) that I need.

Comment: I think making it bidirectional is a good idea. What say you? You just need to add one more suggestion here regarding the `Category` class.

Answer (score 2):

As Bozho suggested,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) // Gonna be eager by default anyway
@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")
private Category category;
```

Plus this in your Category class to make it bidirectional,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Expense> expense;
```

You need not do an inner join like that. When you query the expense, the related category will automatically get loaded eagerly, most likely using join.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: Thanks, Pascal. But you always come with a detailed, well formed and much more helpful answer. :)